# upperbound on eigenvalue of $A^TA$, where A is a real square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a real square $n\times n$ matrix $A$, and I would like to give an upperbound on $|\lambda|_{\max}$ on $A^TA$. I wonder is there a good upperbound on  $|\lambda|_{\max}$ of $A^TA$ using only eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010080/relationship-between-the-eigenvalues-of-at-a-and-the-maximum-eigenvalue-of-a). See also [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/230058/relation-between-eigenvalues-of-a-and-ata).

Comment: Thanks! I checked those two post. For the first post I don't think they gave an upperbound. For the second post, it seems like there is no easy upperbound on eigenvalue of $A^TA$?

Answer (score 2):

No such upper bound exists (in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$)

Note, for instance, that the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0\\t&0}, \quad t > 0
$$
has only $0$ as an eigenvalue.  However, 
$$
A^TA = \pmatrix{t^2&0\\0&0}
$$
has $t^2$ as its maximal eigenvalue, which can be made arbitrarily large.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

An upper bound on  $|\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)|$ can be provided in terms of the singular values of $A$, call them $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_n$ (not eigenvalues as requested, but doable with singular values).

Because $A^TA$ is symmetric positive semidefinite, all its eigenvalues are nonnegative, therefore, $\lambda_{\max}(A^TA) \le trace(A^TA)$.

Applying [Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequalities#Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality) , and because the singular values of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same, $trace(A^TA) \le \Sigma_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2$, which actually holds with equality in this case.

So $\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)  \le \Sigma_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^2$

I make no claim that this is the best possible bound.